# Processing modelines in Eclipse/Netbeans

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, plugins, syntax-highlighting

The company I work for has lots of files written in C++ that are saved without extension. They have a convention of naming C libraries with .h and C++ libraries without extension.

If I want such files to be loaded with syntax highlight in Eclipse, I have to load these files one by one, and select the language in which each of the files is written, which is C++. I tried to use Netbeans, but it stumbles on the same difficult.

Many of the files are annotated with the following metadata on the first line, which I think is a hint for the editor vi to trigger the syntax highlighting.

```
// vi:set ft=cpp: -*- Mode: C++ -*-
```

I couldn't find any plugin that automatically detects the programming language on a file. My question is:

Is it possible to instruct Netbeans or Eclipse to assume that a file without extension is written in C/C++? Alternatively, how can I make use of the vi directives to trigger syntax highlighting in Eclipse/Netbeans?

The original title of this post was: Automatic detection of language for files without extension in Eclipse/Netbeans.

Comment: This conversation (https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-noext-mime-resolver/issues/13) is related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans, the plugin netbeans-noext-mime-resolver now can be used to automatically trigger the syntax highlighting using if the source-code is contains the modeline:

```
// vi:set ft=cpp: -*- Mode: C++ -*-
```

Thanks to junichi11 for that! The discussion on adding support to modeline for this plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-noext-mime-resolver/issues/13). I had tried jVi (http://jvi.sourceforge.net/), but I couldn't get it working to trigger the syntax as I expected.

AFAIK, the issue remains open for Eclipse. It would be nice to have the same feature there.